# Define varables in Excel then use in Access VBA at same time

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

Is it possible to define a string variable in excel and then use that variable inside Access?
I have a program where in Excel a window pops up asking for where a file is located which will feed into an Access database - get processed - then shoot into Excel. The problem is that this is for a lot of different people and so each computer is going to have its own extension address of where the file is located, so it is necessary to have it be easy for users to identify where their file is located instead of hard-coding it into the VBA.

No matter what I try, I can't seem to figure out how to get the string variable to talk to the access database so it knows where to go look for the file.
I can't seem to find a solution for this. Anyone have any ideas?

Here is the code I have so far: This is what is inside the excel file----

```
'CommandButton1 is a button inside of a form window that pops up for the user to enter the address of the file

Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'both of these are public/global variables defined in a global macro
locationaddress = txbBrowse2.Value
LocationOfData = txbBrowse.Value

Dim appAccess As Object
Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")

'location of data is the location of the access file itself
location address is the string that I'm trying to feed into access
appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase LocationOfData, exclusive:=False
appAccess.Application.Run "DoExcelImport"
End Sub

'Here is the code inside the access file, the idea is that it will modify the "Import-TEST" saved import. It will change where it pulls the excel sheet that contains a bunch of items that requires access to process.

Sub DoExcelImport()
DoCmd.SetWarnings False

    Dim ies As ImportExportSpecification, i As Long, oldXML() As String, newXML As String

    Set ies = CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications("Import-TEST")
    oldXML = Split(ies.XML, vbCrLf, -1, vbBinaryCompare)
    newXML = ""
    For i = 0 To UBound(oldXML)
        If i = 1 Then
            ' re-write the second line of the existing XML
            newXML = newXML & _
                    "<ImportExportSpecification Path = """ & _
                    locationaddress & _
                    """ xmlns=""urn:www.microsoft.com/office/access/imexspec"">" & _
                    vbCrLf
        Else
            newXML = newXML & oldXML(i) & vbCrLf
        End If
    Next
    ies.XML = newXML
    ies.Execute
    Set ies = Nothing
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the program entirely in Excel? How are you trying to communicate with Access? Which versions of the software are you using?

Comment: office 2013. I added some code and detail to the question.

Comment: I would guess the `Sub DoExcelImport` should have an input argument i.e. `name as string` and then you can pass the argument in with application.run

Comment: That didn't seem to work. I declared the variable as public inside the access file, but when the macro is ran it doesn't read the variable as having any value (see it as blank/empty) because the value is assigned inside the excel file. Maybe I don't understand what you mean by "can pass the argument in with application.run"?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way might be using

```
SaveSettings(AppName As String, Section As String,Key As String, Setting As `String)
```

to store the string in the registry,
    GetSettings((AppName As String, Section As String,Key As String)
to get it in Access, and

```
DeleteSetting (AppName as String)
```

to delete it.
Is probably a bit abusing the registry, but an easy way.

Comment: I tried setting up the SaveSettings inside the excel macro:
SaveSettings("MyApp", "Directory", "LocationAddress", locationaddress)
But it keeps giving me a compiling error, that it is missing an "=" Which doesn't make sense to me because even Microsoft's site doesn't mention an "=" with this expression.